# Broadcasted tranform throws exception upon lookup

Tags: ros2, tf2-ros

I am using ROS 2. My code is throwing an exception even though I have just created the transform above it. Please see the code snippet below:

```py
link = tf2_ros.Link("cam_" + str(id))

# Publish the link to the TF tree
self.br.sendTransform(link)

transform_stamped = TransformStamped()
transform_stamped.header.stamp = self.get_clock().now().to_msg()
transform_stamped.header.frame_id = "camera_link"
transform_stamped.child_frame_id = "cam_" + str(id)
transform_stamped.transform.translation.x = x
transform_stamped.transform.translation.y = y
transform_stamped.transform.translation.z = z
transform_stamped.transform.rotation.x = quaternion[0]
transform_stamped.transform.rotation.y = quaternion[1]
transform_stamped.transform.rotation.z = quaternion[2]
transform_stamped.transform.rotation.w = quaternion[3]
self.br.sendTransform(transform_stamped)

to_frame_rel = "camera_link"
from_frame_rel = "cam_" + str(id)
try:
    # look up for the transformation between 'obj_1' and 'base_link' frames
    t = self.tf_buffer.lookup_transform(to_frame_rel, from_frame_rel, rclpy.time.Time())  
    self.get_logger().info(f"Successfully received data!")
except TransformException as e:
    self.get_logger().info(f"Could not transform {to_frame_rel} to {from_frame_rel}: {e}")
    return
```

Below is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/saz/colcon_ws/install/ur_description/lib/ur_description/task1a.py", line 521, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/saz/colcon_ws/install/ur_description/lib/ur_description/task1a.py", line 506, in main
      rclpy.spin(aruco_tf_class) # spining on the object to make it alive in ROS 2 DDS
  File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/__init__.py", line 222, in spin
      executor.spin_once()
  File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 713, in spin_once
      raise handler.exception()
  File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/task.py", line 239, in __call__
      self._handler.send(None)
  File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 418, in handler
      await call_coroutine(entity, arg)
  File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 332, in _execute_timer
      await await_or_execute(tmr.callback)
  File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 107, in await_or_execute
      return callback(*args)
  File "/home/saz/colcon_ws/install/ur_description/lib/ur_description/task1a.py", line 479, in process_image
      transform_stamped_base_link.transform = self.tf_buffer.lookup_transform('base_link', 'cam_' + str(id), self.get_clock().now().to_msg())
  File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tf2_ros/buffer.py", line 136, in lookup_transform
      return self.lookup_transform_core(target_frame, source_frame, time)
  tf2.LookupException: "cam_49" passed to lookupTransform argument source_frame does not exist. 
  [ros2run]: Process exited with failure 1
```

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! 
The exception says about `cam_49`. Unfortunately, your code does not show us the value of `id`. Are you sure that `cam_49` is published?